# Lombok и аннотация @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, аннотации, lombok

Добавил в проект библиотеку Lombok.

Дело в том, что я обычно иньектю спринг бины через `@Autowired` над сеттерами или конструктором. Вроде бы как это безопаснее, чем над полями из-за возможных циклических зависимостей.

Но переведя проект на Lombok, использую аннотацию `@Data`, соответственно геттеров/сеттеров не видно. И не понятно как авто инжектить бины с помощью `@Autowired`. Над чем её ставить? Или как заинжектить без этой аннотации?

Comment: @RomanC а есть другие варианты? Просто ситуация же совершенно стандартная, может в ломбок аннотациях что-то есть на этот случай? Сейчас вот сижу изучаю, пока вариантов не нашёл...

Comment: Лучше всего внедрять зависимости через конструктор. Ничего дополнительно делать не нужно (для stateless бинов используйте `@Value`, для остальных - `@Data`), spring внедрит зависимости сам. Циклические зависимости - признак плохого дизайна, избавьтесь от них.

Comment: @RomanKonoval а конструктор нужно прописать в явном виде или через Ломбок? И куда именно ставить Data, над чем?

Comment: @RomanC в смысле не использовать?)

Comment: @RomanC я правда не понял, что значит "просто забудьте про Lombok"? Он за кодогенерацию отвечает, чтобы бойлерплейт кода не было, его приходится использовать. Или что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: @Sergey Lombok является внешней библиотекой, т.е. она не входит в состав Java SE и Java EE, поэтому ее использование  опционально.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Value` и `@Data` скорее про POJO, Entity и идемпотентность.
Чаще под бинами, которые еще и `@Autowired` имеют в виду `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Component` и их производные.

Достаточно объявить переменную инъектируемого бина как `pivate final` и использовать аннотацию Lombok `@RequiredArgsConstructor`.

Вот пример для абстрактного `User` в вакууме.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {
  //
}

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
  //
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService {
  private final UserRepository;
  //
}

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {
  private final UserService;
  //
}
```

`UserRepository` -> `UserService` -> `UserController`

Answer (score 1):

Циклические зависимости - признак плохого дизайна, избавьтесь от них. Лучше всего внедрять зависимости через конструктор.

Если внедрение по типу годится, то ничего дополнительно делать не нужно (для stateless бинов используйте @Value, для остальных - @Data) - конструктор сгенерированный lombok будет работать, а spring внедрит зависимости сам.

Пример, как должен выглядеть сервис:

```
@Value
public SomeService {
  AnotherService anotherService;
  YetAnotherService yetAnotherService;

  public void someMethod () {
     anotherService.call();
  }
}
```